# Speed up datetime formatting when reading csv

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a csv file with 4+m records.

I import it using pd.read_csv('big_file.csv', dtype=object)

This file has 2 columns with dates in the following format: 
'yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss.nsTZ' e.g.'2018-05-05T04:39:09.447Z'

I need to transform them to 
'yyyy-mm-dd H:M:S' e.g. '2018-09-23 06:03:12'

I use the following code to do so:

```py
df['created'] = pd.to_datetime(arg=df.created).dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
df['lastLogin'] = pd.to_datetime(arg=df.lastLogin).dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
df['lastUpdated'] = pd.to_datetime(arg=df.lastUpdated).dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
df['created'] = pd.to_datetime(arg=df.created)
df['lastLogin'] = pd.to_datetime(arg=df.lastLogin)
df['lastUpdated'] = pd.to_datetime(arg=df.lastUpdated)
```

This process is extremely slow:

```
CPU times: user 1min 48s, sys: 1.19 s, total: 1min 49s
Wall time: 1min 49s
```

Is there a way to speed it up?

Comment: What is `TZ`? Are you converting from one time zone to another time zone?

Comment: TZ is a timezone. all data in csv is in iso format 2018-05-05T04:39:09.447Z where 'Z' is UTC=0

Comment: Do you want the output in the same time zone as in the input? In other words, do you guarantee that there is no time zone conversion? If it is guaranteed, why don't you just use string methods. You'll save the calculation for interpreting the string as date and time.

Comment: Hi, norio, yes, the output will be in the same timezone. Overall, I'm fine with the naive datetime format without a timezone at all.
The reason why I do the conversion is to a) change format from utc to more human readable b) to use it in further plots using primarily plotly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comment, I understand that you don't need the meaning of the dates but you just want to change the aesthetic appearance of the strings representing the dates. Then, you can just treat the data simply as strings. So, I did it like this.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import numpy as np
import sys

def gen_sample(numdata, outfname):
    yy=np.random.randint(1905, 2018, 2*numdata)
    mm=np.random.randint(   1,   13, 2*numdata)
    dd=np.random.randint(   1,   29, 2*numdata)
    hhh=np.random.randint(   0,   25, 2*numdata)
    mmm=np.random.randint(   0,   61, 2*numdata)
    sss=np.random.randint(   0,   61, 2*numdata)
    baboon=np.random.randint(   0, 1000, 2*numdata)
    with open(outfname, 'w') as outf:
        for jj in range(numdata):
            outf.write('%4.4i-%2.2i-%2.2iT%2.2i:%2.2i:%2.2i.%3.3iZ,%4.4i-%2.2i-%2.2iT%2.2i:%2.2i:%2.2i.%3.3iZ\n'
                       %(yy[2*jj],   mm[2*jj],   dd[2*jj],
                         hhh[2*jj],  mmm[2*jj],  sss[2*jj],  baboon[2*jj],
                         yy[2*jj+1], mm[2*jj+1], dd[2*jj+1],
                         hhh[2*jj+1], mmm[2*jj+1], sss[2*jj+1], baboon[2*jj+1]))


def convert(infname,outfname):

    data=np.loadtxt(infname, dtype=np.str, delimiter=',', ndmin=2)
    with open(outfname,'w') as outf:
        for jr in range(data.shape[0]):
            outf.write('%s %s,%s %s\n'%(
                data[jr,0][0:10],
                data[jr,0][11:19],
                data[jr,1][0:10],
                data[jr,1][11:19] ))


if __name__=='__main__':
    sample_fname= 'daa.csv'
    out_fname= 'daadaa.csv'
    if len(sys.argv)>1:
        numdata=int(sys.argv[1])
        gen_sample(numdata, sample_fname)
    else:
        convert(sample_fname, out_fname)
```

and it took me about 15 seconds for 4M*2 data on my computer. Please see this

```
#!/bin/bash

for jj in 0 1 2
do
  echo "generating sample.."
  ./main.py 4000000
  echo "loading, converting, and writing.."
  echo "----"
  /usr/bin/time ./main.py 
  echo "----"
done
```

and this

```
$ ./run.sh 
generating sample..
loading, converting, and writing..
----
14.96user 0.94system 0:15.05elapsed 105%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 818724maxresident)k
8inputs+312504outputs (0major+315787minor)pagefaults 0swaps
----
generating sample..
loading, converting, and writing..
----
14.91user 0.93system 0:14.99elapsed 105%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 818848maxresident)k
16inputs+312504outputs (0major+315864minor)pagefaults 0swaps
----
generating sample..
loading, converting, and writing..
----
15.39user 0.95system 0:15.52elapsed 105%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 818736maxresident)k
8inputs+312504outputs (0major+315857minor)pagefaults 0swaps
----
```

Input file is like

```
$ head daa.csv 
2016-10-05T08:07:03.214Z,1973-10-01T12:36:21.367Z
1961-08-24T02:08:57.436Z,1953-03-06T00:56:12.486Z
1986-09-07T17:15:60.322Z,1952-11-19T19:02:56.159Z
1939-08-17T05:13:19.659Z,1920-12-15T16:46:52.628Z
2004-11-09T02:29:25.905Z,1925-02-07T10:37:49.142Z
2011-12-12T10:46:38.583Z,1992-02-10T08:58:60.284Z
1968-01-23T05:05:05.151Z,1935-09-17T07:12:49.392Z
1916-04-05T18:55:35.281Z,1919-10-12T10:05:10.249Z
1970-10-04T21:45:16.751Z,1951-01-08T16:58:51.190Z
1910-01-19T22:12:04.088Z,2006-03-08T09:26:45.690Z
```

Output file was like

```
$ head daadaa.csv 
2016-10-05 08:07:03,1973-10-01 12:36:21
1961-08-24 02:08:57,1953-03-06 00:56:12
1986-09-07 17:15:60,1952-11-19 19:02:56
1939-08-17 05:13:19,1920-12-15 16:46:52
2004-11-09 02:29:25,1925-02-07 10:37:49
2011-12-12 10:46:38,1992-02-10 08:58:60
1968-01-23 05:05:05,1935-09-17 07:12:49
1916-04-05 18:55:35,1919-10-12 10:05:10
1970-10-04 21:45:16,1951-01-08 16:58:51
1910-01-19 22:12:04,2006-03-08 09:26:45
```

If you don't need to write the converted data back to a file, 
maybe the run time will be faster.
You will need to make the function more robust for the variation of your own data, but I hope the idea is delivered.

Answer (score 1):

Since your timestamps follow a non-standard format, I recommend using  the parameters **parse_dates** and **date_parser** with a custom parser when reading the csv file, e.g.:

```
parser = lambda date: pd.datetime.strptime(date, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%Z')
df = pd.read_csv('big_file.csv', 
                 parse_dates=['created', 'lastLogin', 'lastUpdated'],
                 date_parser=parser)
```

From [pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html)

> **date_parser : function, optional**
>
> Function to use for converting a sequence of string columns to an array of datetime instances. The default uses dateutil.parser.parser to do the conversion. Pandas will try to call date_parser in three different ways, advancing to the next if an exception occurs: 1) Pass one or more arrays (as defined by parse_dates) as arguments; 2) concatenate (row-wise) the string values from the columns defined by parse_dates into a single array and pass that; and **3) call date_parser once for each row using one or more strings (corresponding to the columns defined by parse_dates) as arguments**.

Comment: Hi, ottovon.
Thank you for your advice. I did some testing and it looks like pd.to_datetime is faster than parse_dates=[],infer_datetime_format=True

CPU times: user 49.4 s, sys: 4.28 s, total: 53.7 s
vs
CPU times: user 1min 17s, sys: 3.86 s, total: 1min 21s

Comment: Hey, Alexander. I will take a look at it. There is a way to pass a parser in the parameters of **pd.read_csv**. This loss in performance is probably due to pandas' inability to infer your timestamp formating.

Comment: @AlexanderPennie, check out the edited version of my answer.